# Why can't I import a function in Python using the "as" syntax?

Tags: python, python-import

Why does this work,

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
```

but not the other?

```
import sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error as mse
```

This gives

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error'

It is not possible because `mean_squared_error` is a function is my guess?

Comment: @RocketHazmat i know that works. I didn't to get something that works but why what I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot `import sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error` because it is not a module but a function, yes. The `as` part stands completely independently. So you can, for example, `from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as mse`.

Comment: I know that as implied in my question title. But what I want is *why*.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm supposed to answer that. If "it is not a module" isn't an adequate explanation for "why do I get an error message saying `no module named...`", then I don't know what would be. Questions about why language designers made the design decisions they did are not a good fit for Stack Overflow; unless there is an authoritative interview with the designers, we are speculating and offering opinions.